# Is it better to store coordinates in an array or two ints?

Tags: java, arrays, int, coordinates

I'm writing a program in Java that has Character objects with x and y positions. I'm wondering if it is better to store the object's coordinates in an array, or to just store the position in two ints.

I can store it in an array:

```
Integer[] pos = {1, 5};
```

or in two Integers:

```
Integer x = 1;
Integer y = 5;
```

Which is better?

Comment: I think, in java, it is recommend to encapsulate any necessary data into class.!

Comment: I suppose that depends entirely on what you're trying to accomplish. You haven't provided any code (which is highly recommended for StackOverflow) so there's not much to go on.

Comment: @Rugal, sometimes it is okay to use built-in data types for their intended purpose, rather than making a class for everything.

Comment: @SimonT  yes, so I add `necessary` as my word!

Comment: What are you going to do with this data? How is it used? The "best" way of handling it depends on the usage (like almost everything in programming). That said, I think I would recommend a class with different variables in most cases. You can make it immutable (eliminating the need for defensive copying), and it usually becomes simpler to understand the meaning of the data and the code that uses it. If, however, it's only going to be used in a method or two, a class may not really be worth it.

Comment: define `better` and show some code and state a problem as this is not a real question.

Comment: you can make use of Point or Point2D.Double or Point2D.Float [available in java.awt.geom.Point2D]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Idiomatic version of a bare Struct type class in Java

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Coordinate(@Nonnull final int x, @Nonnul final int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() { return String.format("%d/%d", this.x, this.y); }

    public int hashCode() { return this.toString().hashCode(); }

    public boolean equals(@Nullable final Object o) { return this.equals((Coordinate)o); }

    public boolean equals(@Nullable final Coordinate c) { return this.x = c.x && this.y == c.y; }
}
```

[Concern yourself with **correctness** first, **maintainability** second and **performance** only when you  detect a problem and profile and measure the problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

> The above class is pretty much the bare minimum to operate in general
>   programming cases with standard library containers and behave
>   correctly. `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` are important when working
>   with `Map` containers especially. `.toString()` is a nice way to get a
>   nice human readable representation and a consistent `.hashCode()` at
>   the same time.
>
> This design also eschews `setters` and `getters` since it is immutable they are just
>   syntactic overhead.
>
> `getters` in this design are just fine performance wise because the `JIT` compiler will
>   eventually inline them because of the use of `final` is a hint to the optimizer.
>
> I just chose not to include them for space and style reasons.

Not much can beat an immutable data only structure in normal cases, and you get `thread` safety with no locking/synchronization issues as a bonus.

`@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` annotations are available from [`com.google.code.findbugs`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.code.findbugs%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jsr305%22) JSR-305 library.

Comment: Thank you, this makes me realize I should only do what's easiest to program instead of worrying about vague stuff I'm not sure of.

Comment: If you replace `easiest` with `most idiomatic` then you learned a very valuable lesson that many extremely "senior" or "experienced" programmers never learn! *Easiest* isn't always *most correct*.